# How to start azure VM automatically without automation account

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

We have a Virtual Machine which scheduled to stop automatically on every end of the day.

Next day when we want to connect to it, we need to explicitly login to Azure portal, select Virtual machine and click on start.

I know we can schedule it using automation account (due to some restrictions in office environment cant use automation account) but is there any way we can achieve this? 
Thinking of any way of -

- Creating a batch file on my local machine which just start the VM
  when I run it without logging into Azure portal?
- Any other simple setting like we have to schedule auto stop?

Any other hint will be a great help.
Thank you!

Comment: Instead of Automation account, can you use Timer Triggered Azure Function?

Comment: Not aware of this, any reference please?

Comment: Timer Triggered Azure Function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp. Also take a look at this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/powershell-support-in-azure-functions-is-now-generally-available/

Comment: Thank you @Gaurav. Will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use az cli and\or powershell and script the vm to start, its extremely straight forward (something like `az vm start -g rg_name -n vm_name`).

There are no built-in startup solutions yet.

Comment: yeah, why not??